# Handle Calender popup in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium to scrape data from a travel website. I am having a hard time automating the date selection due to the calendar pop-up thing. My code is:

```
library(svDialogs)
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(string)

remDr = rsDriver(port= sample(100:9999, 1), chromever = "93.0.4577.63")
remDr <- remDr[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.booking.com/")

remDr$findElement('class','sb-date-field__controls sb-date-field__controls__ie-fix')$setElementAttribute('value',"Mon, Oct 18")
```

Please guide me on how I can select the value from Calender for Check-in and Check out.

Thanks

Comment: I thought about your problem and I got down that you could detect the xpath of each day and from that, thanks to a for loop or similar, you can iterate and choose the range of date that you need. I don't know if this will help you, but it is just an input.